# Is this a one of the only ways to legally avoid data privacy laws for payment processing?

Tags: privacy

Stripe offers a [checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) system where there is a **stripe** hosted page. Here I am redirecting the user to stripe's page for payment. So in that case I am not collecting anything . I am just redirecting to stripe's page. Will link to the following page: https://stripe.com/en-in/privacy
and state that we do not selling data from stripe except to required legal authorities under obligation. So basically all information is collected by stripe directly by their data requests must be addressed by stripe. So I am NOT liable    right?*This is a brilliant service from [stripe](https://stripe.com).*

Comment: Just as tax avoidance is not a crime but tax evasion is , this is liability avoidance.

Comment: Which law are you worried about?

Comment: The CCPA charging $7500 per person . I am also scared of GDPR demanding $20 million and the strange right to refunds in EU

Comment: I respect all jurisdictions their sovreignity and right to make laws but I just cannot understand why they are torturing with GDPR CCPA ePrivacy Directive CalOPPA PIPEDA and EU refund laws.

Comment: How about replacing the links to Stripe with a more neutral term, like payment processing service? As it is, I almost voted to close because it looks like spam.

Comment: @astackexchangeuser 1) the numbers you are worried about are maximums, if the court finds you were extremely guilty with blatant disregard for the law, not if you tried to follow it and made a small mistake, and 2) form a LLC

Answer (score 2):

### So you’re not collecting payment data. What about all the other data?

So you have a user. You direct them to stripe. They come back. How do you know they paid?

You have to be collecting some personal data that links the user who left to the user who returned as well as something that links them to the payment.

You have to comply with the law for that data.

Comment: But that data is not so sensitive!

Comment: That data is under my controller and I can comply but in other cases I will have to gaurentee stripe complies.

Comment: I don't think I will be given a huge fibe.(finre)

Comment: Some 100 million dollars or some thing for CCPA or 20 million dollars for GDPR.

Comment: Can you just tell how these large number of apps get away without showing GDPR or CCPA notice?

Comment: Can bussinessd insurance protect against CCPA $7500 is too much $7.5 would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

For small and medium businesses, it can be an *excellent* idea to turn to a payment provider who specializes in such services. There are more than the one mentioned by the OP. Lawfully handling credit card data on your own site is a *serious* hassle.

The business would still be required to handle all other personal data in accordance with all applicable laws and regulations. The EU has decided that their GDPR applies worldwide as long as the data subject is in the EU. (Extraterritorial laws are hardly unusual, just look at US sanctions on various rogue nations, but enforcement can be spotty.)